# Doctrine: load from fixture not working

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

For some reason all table field values are being entered as "array". Don't know what is going on. I am using symfony/doctrine, and the command `php symfony doctrine:data-load`. Anyone who used this in the past should know what I'm talking about.

What could cause all fixture values to be interpreted incorrectly, and entered as 'array'?

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of your schema and fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT keep any unrelated files or directories inside your fixture directory. Once I removed some unrelated yml files and directories, everything worked fine.

Hope this helps future users.